# How to display length of schools in HTML using javascript google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api

I have the below code where I am displaying the nearby schools with respect to  current location using Places Service. I have the count of schools as well which gives 20 in the below code. Now I need to know how to display this 20 in HTML .

HTML code:

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
{{lengthOfSchools}}
```

JS code:

```
 getSchoolsList() {
    var markers = [];
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let originLat, originLng;
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        originLat = position.coords.latitude;
        originLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.getlocation = {
          origin: { latitude: originLat, longitude: originLng }
        };
        this.srcOriginLatitude = this.getlocation.origin.latitude;
        this.srcOriginLongitude = this.getlocation.origin.longitude;
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: { lat: this.srcOriginLatitude, lng: this.srcOriginLongitude },
          radius: 10000,
          type: ['school']
        }, (results, status) => {
          this.lengthOfSchools = results.length;
          console.log(this.lengthOfSchools); // displays 20
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {


            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var place = results[i];
              console.log(" Places... ", place);
              var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                icon: './assets/images/marker_active.png',
              });
              marker.setMap(map);

            }
          }
        });
      });

    }
  }
```

Comment: just use a variable "count", in your service use this.count=result.length and in .html write {{count}}

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesnt work. As you see in the above code, I am storing the count in this.lengthOfSchools and binding that to HTML , but it doesnt display in HTML.

Comment: I think that i's a ngZone problem, I don't know if my answer work, but I hope it appoint in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's a problem of [ngZones](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone). When we call a function "outside" angular, Angular don't know when must to repaint.

I think you need make some like

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {} //inject ngZone

...
service.nearbySearch({
  ...
}(results, status) => {
   //replace the line
   //   this.lengthOfSchools = results.length;
   //by
   this.zone.run(() => {
     this.lengthOfSchools = results.length;
   });
```